# Always release a QSemaphore before deleting?

Tags: c++, qt, semaphore

- Does a QSemaphore need to be released before deletion?
- If yes, I should call `semaphore->release(n)` before `delete semaphore`, but how do I know how many (`n`) resources are acquired? (I know how many resources are `available()`, but not the overall "size" of the semaphore.)

Reason for my question: <sub>I'm hunting down memory leaks and found a QSemaphore that created a memory leak although `delete` was (seems to have been) called on it. Maybe that happened because it was not released correctly - [The doc](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsemaphore.html#dtor.QSemaphore) says "***Warning:*** Destroying a semaphore that is in use may result in undefined behavior."</sub>

<sub>**Edit:** The memory leak actually was the result of a memory dump function placed before all objects were destroyed. Adding an extra scope `{ ... }` helped there. Nevertheless, my question remains.</sub>

Comment: Maybe you should reword this a bit. "that wasn't deleted although delete was called on it." does not make sense. when you call delete on it, the object will be destroyed. Did you maybe mean it wasn't released?

Comment: I rephrased my question. The semaphore shows up in the list of memory leaks - if it's actually not deleted, I can't say, just that it doesn't seem to be released / deleted *correctly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you need to *release* a semaphore before destruction, as `release()` just adds a specified number of *resources* (aka *permits*) to the semaphore. If you look at the examples for QSemaphore, you can find that `release()` can increase the number of available permits beyond the initial amount.

What the doc says is that no thread should *operate* with the semaphore that is being destroyed. In other words, all threads should complete their calls of the semaphore object methods, whatever those are, before it can be safely destroyed. And the class itself has no support for this; it's solely application responsibility to ensure that, by external means. Actually, it's a common situation in multi-threaded programming that destruction of an object (even a synchronization object) that is still in use is unsafe.